Analytic branches of the logarithm in given regions
Question:
In which of the following regions is it possible to define an analytic branch of the logarithm? Justify your answer and display such branch in the regions where it is possible.
$a) D_1 = $ {$ z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 < |z| < e$};
$b) D_2 = $ {$z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < Im z - Re z < 1$};
$c) D_3 = \Delta (0, 1)$\{ $ti \in \mathbb{C} : 0 \leq t \leq 1$}.
So I know that we can define $f: A \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = e^z$ and then $f'$ would never vanish in $\mathbb{c}$ and, thus, $g: D_1 \to \mathbb{c}$ is an analytic branch of $f^{-1}$ in $D_1$ if and only if $g$ is continuous (we also know that $0 \notin D_1$).
Now, an analytic branch of $f^{-1}$ in $D_1$ is also called an analytic branch of the logarithm in $D_1$
So i tried defining $g$ such that $g(z) = Log z = Log|z| + i Arg z$ but I don't think the function would be continuous in $D_1$...


For $D_1$, the region is similar to this green annulus. The region does not contain the branch point $z=0$. However, as it encircles this branch point you need to define a branch cut. For example, the principal branch $|\arg(z)|<\pi$ will do de job although $\log(z)$ won't be analytic in all $D_1$ since you are excluding the real segment $(-e,-1)$.

$D_2$ is the region between the lines $\Im z = \Re z$ and $\Im z = \Re z +1 $ (it does not contain these lines, just the interior). The branch point $z=0$ is not inside the region and we can make $\log(z)$ to be analytic in all the $D_2$ with the branch $0<\arg(z)<2\pi$.



If I understood your notation $D_3$ is the unit circle minus the real non-negative axis. Simply use the branch $0<\arg(z)<2\pi$ and $\ln(z)$ will be analytic in all the region.

Some terminology:
Consider
$$ \log(z) = \ln|z| + i(\arg(z)+2\pi n) \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
This function defined as it is, is nor continuous nor analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ and is multivalued.
However if $n=0$ and we restrict $-\pi<\arg(z)\leq \pi$ we make the function single-valued. This domain is called the principal value of  $\log(z)$.
If we restrict further the argument $-\pi<\arg(z)<\pi$ the function is continuous and analytic. This is called the principal branch of $\log(z)$.
The ray $\arg(z)=\pi$ is called the branch cut for the principal branch.
We can define other branches $\alpha<\arg(z)<\alpha + 2\pi$ where $\ln(z)$ is analytic. In this case the branch cut is $\arg(z) = \alpha$.
Finally, the point $z=0$ common to all branch cuts for the multiple-valued function is called a branch point.

If $0$ is not in your region, then you can define a branch of the logarithm function in a path connected region $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ by picking some $u\in U$ and some path $\beta$, avoiding $0$, from $1$ to $u$, and setting  $$\log(v)= \int_\beta\frac 1zdz+\int_\gamma \frac 1z dz,$$
where $\gamma$ is a path in $U$, avoiding $0$, from $u$ to $v$.  This is independent of the choice of $\gamma$, as long as we do not have an alternative path $\gamma'$, such that the loop $\gamma\circ \gamma'$ winds around $0$ a non-zero number of times.
So for each of your regions, if your region contains a loop around the origin, then you cannot define the branch.  Conversely, if your region is disjoint from a line starting at the origin, and going out to infinity (known as a branch cut), then it cannot contain a loop around the origin.
In each case (a), (b), (c) you can either find a loop or a branch cut.

so we can only define an analytic branch of the logarithm in $D_2$ and $D_3$, right?

i cant see why $D_3$ would contain the origin since it seems to have excluded all points where the real part is zero and the imaginary part is given by ti with t in [0,1]

so the origin was excluded from $D_3$

Sorry I misread the definition of $D_3$ - you are right you are excluding the origin.  In particular, the non-negative imaginary axis gives you a branch cut disjoint from $D_3$.
